# Have been vs. were

Tags: differences

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> 1. "There have been many civilizations throughout history."
> 2. "There were many civilizations throughout history."

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another as a start.

Answer (score 1):

1) In first case, those civilizations still exist, or, at least, their influences still exist. 
2) In second case, those civilizations are all lost and long-gone.